# Как через winapi использовать управление DTR?

Tags: winapi, c++

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как в дочернем окне приложения вывести графическую индикацию установки в 1 и сбрасывания в 0 линии DTR (C++).

Answer (score 2):

1. Использовать функцию [GetCommState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363260(v=VS.85).aspx) для получения значения флагов интересующего порта.
2. Вывести любым подходящим способом полученное значение бита DTR в графический интерфейс (выставить чекбокс на форме, например).